# Hola, estoy intentando hacer un formulario para mi portafolio en angular, sin embargo tengo un error con el método post, alguien sabe alguna solución?

Tags: html5, angular

```
//contact-form.component.ts
import { Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { SendFormService } from '../../services/send-form.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './contact-form.component.css'
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactFormComponent {
  constructor(private router:Router, private sendData:SendFormService){
  }
  submitForm(formData: any) {
    const name=formData.value.name;
    console.log(name);
    this.sendData.submitData(formData);
  }
}

//send-form.services.ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SendFormService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  submitData(data:NgForm){
    this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:5074",data.value.name)
    .subscribe({
      next:response=>{console.log(response)},
      error: error=>console.log(error)}
    );
  }  
}
//contact-form.component.html
<div class="container-contact-form container-fluid w-100 h-auto d-flex flex-column align-items-center mx-auto mb-2 ">
    <h3 class="text-center mt-3">
        <a href="/"><img src="../../../assets/arrow-narrow-left.svg" alt=""></a>
        Contactame directamente</h3>
    
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 h-100 mx-auto rounded pb-2 pt-2 ">
        <form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm)"
        class="flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-center align-items-center w-100  w-md-100 h-75 gap-1 rounded">
            <label class="d-block mb-1 mx-auto w-sm-75 w-75">Dejame un mensaje</label>
            <input  
            id="name"  type="text" class="rounded d-block mb-1 mx-auto w-75 w-sm-75" placeholder="nombre"> <!--name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"-->
            <textarea id="message"type="text" class="rounded d-block mb-1 mx-auto w-75 w-sm-75" placeholder="mensaje"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="rounded d-block mb-1 mx-auto w-75 w-sm-75">
        </form>
        <!-- TODO: verificar que si se centre con la ubicacion -->
        <div class="flex-column flex-sm-row ml-sm-3 mx-auto justify-content-center mx-auto align-items-center w-100">
            <div class="text-center ">
                <p class="lh-1">Ciudad juarez, Chih.</p>
                <p class="lh-1 ">CP. 32180</p>
                <p class="lh-1"><img  src="../../../assets/phone.svg" alt="phone">+526969696</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container-contact-form container-fluid w-50 h-auto d-flex flex-column align-items-center mx-auto p-0">
                <img class="w-100 h-50 rounded" src="../../../assets/angular-17-img.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//el error
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_ContactFormComponent])[_SendFormService -> _SendFormService -> _SendFormService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
at NullInjector.get (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5627:27)
at R3Injector.get (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6070:33)
at R3Injector.get (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6070:33)
at injectInjectorOnly (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:912:40)
at Module.ɵɵinject (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:918:42)
at Object.SendFormService_Factory (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/src/app/services/send-form.service.ts:7:29)
at eval (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6192:43)
at runInInjectorProfilerContext (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:868:9)
at R3Injector.hydrate (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6191:17)
at R3Injector.get (c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Portfolio-Angular/Portfolio-Jesus/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6059:33) {
ngTempTokenPath: null,
ngTokenPath: [
'_SendFormService',
'_SendFormService',
'_SendFormService',
'_HttpClient',
'_HttpClient'
]
}

Comment: intenta inyectas HttpClient en el constructor

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, si ya lo tengo inyectado y nada, aun así muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes corregir este error añadiendo el proveedor HttpClientModule en la sección de imports.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declaraciones: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ]
})
```

Esto lo tenemos que añadir en el archivo src -> app -> app.module.ts.
En caso de que tu componente tenga su propio módulo deberás añadir lo que he comentado antes pero en el módulos del propio componente.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, es angular 17, no posee el NgModule, es que según yo estoy usando bien el método pero nada, aun así muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás importando el `HttpClientModule` en el componente y el servicio `SendFormService` no lo tiene disponible.

Para resolver eso importa el `HttpClientModule` a nivel global:

```
bootstrapApplication(App,{
  providers:[provideHttpClient()]
});
```

[referencia](https://angular.dev/guide/http/setup#providing-httpclient-through-dependency-injection)

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar, efectivamente en mi archivo app.config.ts faltaba el provideHttpClient, al parecer ya obtengo en consola el cuerpo del mensaje, muchas gracias de verdad :D